# Changing app background and status bar color based on current time

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm creating a weather app and i want to change the background and status bar color when time change

ex:
Mid Night -> color = dark blue
Morning -> color = cyan

```
    binding.mainConstraint.background = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(resources,R.drawable.sunset_gradient, null)
    window.statusBarColor = ResourcesCompat.getColor(resources, R.color.sunrise_end, null)
```

but because im checking for the current time so there is boilerplate code that i think there is a better way to do

That how it will look like if i used the way mentiond above

```
    fun test() {
    Time.getTimeState()
    val window = this.window
    if (Time.isMidNight == true) {
        binding.mainConstraint.background =
            ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(resources, R.drawable.midnight_gradient, null)
        window.statusBarColor =
            ResourcesCompat.getColor(resources, R.color.midnight_end, null)
    } else if (Time.isSunrise == true) {
        binding.mainConstraint.background =
            ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(resources, R.drawable.sunrise_gradient, null)
        window.statusBarColor =
            ResourcesCompat.getColor(resources, R.color.sunrise_end, null)
    } else if (Time.isMorning == true) {
        binding.mainConstraint.background =
            ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(resources, R.drawable.morning_gradient, null)
        window.statusBarColor =
            ResourcesCompat.getColor(resources, R.color.morning_end, null)
    } else if (Time.isNoon == true) {
        binding.mainConstraint.background =
            ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(resources, R.drawable.noon_gradient, null)
        window.statusBarColor =
            ResourcesCompat.getColor(resources, R.color.noon_end, null)
    } else if (Time.isAfterNoon == true) {
        binding.mainConstraint.background =
            ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(resources, R.drawable.afternoon_gradient, null)
        window.statusBarColor =
            ResourcesCompat.getColor(resources, R.color.afternoon_end, null)
    } else if (Time.isSunset == true) {
        binding.mainConstraint.background = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(resources, R.drawable.sunset_gradient, null)
        window.statusBarColor = ResourcesCompat.getColor(resources, R.color.sunrise_end, null)
    } else {
        binding.mainConstraint.background =
            ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(resources, R.drawable.night_gradient, null)
        window.statusBarColor =
            ResourcesCompat.getColor(resources, R.color.night_end, null)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way you can remove code duplication:

```
val (backgroundDrawable, statusBarColor) = when {
  Time.isMidNight == true -> R.drawable.midnight_gradient to R.color.midnight_end
  Time.isSunrise == true -> R.drawable.sunrise_gradient to R.color.sunrise_end
  ...
}
binding.mainConstraint.background = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(resources, backgroundDrawable, null)
window.statusBarColor = ResourcesCompat.getColor(resources, statusBarColor, null)
```